# Copying files with certain name to specific directory

Tags: directory

I'm working with large amounts of fMRI data and I need to speed up manipulating directories and subdirectories. I have a large amount of directories for each study participant, and each directory contains a structural imaging file, a functional imaging file and directories "struct' and 'func', like this

```
/rMDD/participant 1
        /file_structural.nii
        /file_functional.nii
        /Struct
        /Funct
```

I need to loop through all those participant subfolders, and copy the .nii file containing "structural" in its name to the Struct subfolder, and the .nii file containing "functional" into the Funct subfolder.
How could i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `bash` script that goes over the directories in your question:

```
#!/bin/bash

# cd to /rMDD
cd /rMDD || exit 1;
for dir in participant*; do
    echo mv "$dir"/{*structural*.nii,Struct/};
    echo mv "$dir"/{*functional*.nii,Funct/};
done;
```

Remove the `echo` keywords when you have verified that it does what you want.